# Use multilanguage resources generated by StronglytypedResourceBuilder in windows form app

Tags: c#, winforms, resources, multilingual

I am working in maintenance windows form app project. Till now project is only in one language. Language text is managed by a resource file generated by `StronglytypedResourceBuilder`. Now I need to add other languages.

Using run custom tool(StronglytypedResourceBuilder) on resource file, my English language resource file generated as `Home.resx` and its Designer file `Home.designer.resx` file with Home as class name.

Now the problem is, if I create file for Spanish language as `Home.es-ES.resx` and run the custom tool to create its designer file it is not generating the class file because I think in this case it will try to generate with same class name `Home.cs` that is not possible.

If I generate file with `HomeES.resx` then its designer class file will be generated with `HomeES` as class name.

In code resources are used as **Resources.Localization.Home.title** at so many places. Now in this case if i have to use resources of HomeES file then i have to use it as **Resources.Localization.HomeES.title** and i have to put condition at each every place in 
code to use resource according to culture that is not feasible.

Problem is critical to explain :D, I hope you understand the scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One class enough. Make sure that Access modifier set to the `Friend` or `Public`.
At run time resources will be used based on the current culture automatically.

If `CultureInfo = "es-ES"` then `title` value from resource file which named as "Home.es-ES.resx will be used.

[MSDN Resources and Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163609.aspx)

[Using Resources for localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)